# Linear programming: Modelling a problem

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, linear-programming

**Exercise.** A forest is in flames and the government is planning a firefighter operation. The fire is of small dimensions and is progressing slowly and it must be extinct after $3$ hours of operations. There will be helicopters and planes mobilized to the forest. They obey the following table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Device} & \text{Efficiency $(m^2/hour)$} & \text{Cost (Euros/hour)} & \text{Personal Necessity}\\ 
\hline
   \text{Helicopter AH1} & 15000 & 2000 & 2 \text{ pilots}\\
\hline
   \text{Tank Airplane} & 40000 & 4000 & \text{2 pilots + 1 operator}\\
\hline
   \text{B67 Airplane} & 85000 & 10000 & \text{2 pilots + 3 operators}\\
\end{array}
The area of the forest covered by fire is $3 000 000$ $m^2$. In the support areas, we have $14$ Airplane pilots available, $10$ Helicopter pilots available and $22$ operators available. Model the problem of minimization of the costs of this operation.

**My attempt and doubts.** I defined the following:
\begin{equation*}
x_1 \rightarrow \text{ number of activity hours of AH1} \\
x_2 \rightarrow \text{ number of activity hours of Tank} \\
x_3 \rightarrow \text{ number of activity hours of B67}
\end{equation*}
And I defined the following restrictions:
\begin{equation*}
1500x_1 +40000x_2 + 85000x_3 \leq 3000000 \\[.25cm]
0 \leq x_{1,2,3} \leq 3 
\end{equation*}
The first one is related to the forest area covered by the fire and the second one is related to the hours the operation must hold. I think these are the only restrictions I should take related to these variables. I defined the objective function as the follwing:
\begin{equation*}
z(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 2000x_1 + 4000x_2 + 10000x_3
\end{equation*}
And the objective would be to minimize this function. Now come my problems:

I wasn't able to define restrictions realted to the number of pilots/operators needed. I have thought about adding new variables to do so, but been unable to (somehow everytime I try it doesn't make sense to me). So this is basically why I am posting this, to know how to model the pilots/operators restrictions. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view we have to fix the operation time at $3$ hours in this model. I don´t see any other way. Then I define the variables in a different way:

\begin{equation*}
x_1 \rightarrow \text{ number Helicopters AH1} \\
x_2 \rightarrow \text{ number of Tank Airplanes} \\
x_3 \rightarrow \text{ number of B67 Airplanes}
\end{equation*}

Then in 3 hours each of the 3 different aircraft types can cover the following areas:

\begin{equation*}
\text{ Helicopter AH1: 15000*3=45000} \\
\text{ Tank Airplane: 40000*3=120000} \\
 \text{ B67 Airplane: 85000*3=255000}
\end{equation*}

The the area-restriction is

$$45000\cdot x_1+120000\cdot x_2+255000\cdot x_3=3000000$$

The cost per hour has to be multiplied by $3$ as well to obtain the cost per aircraft.

And the restriction for the airplane pilots would be $2x_2+2x_3\leq 14$, for instance. Btw, defining variables is the best what you can do in linear programming. Good job, especially in this regard.

Comment: Hi @callculus42 . Sorry for the delay, I have solved the problem using your solution.  Thank you for the help, made a lot of sense to me fixing the $3$ hours! I guess that's what I was missing :D

Comment: @Seabourn I can comprehend your confusion. In my view the exsercise isn´t very clear formulated..